# Ubuntu 23.04 keep crashing

Tags: kernel, crash, 23.04

I'm new to Linux, I don't know what's happening.
This is HP Elitebook Folio 9470m running Ubuntu Lunar Lobster.
I just installed this today.

[image]

Comment: This is the symptom.  The actual error was much earlier.  The most likely cause is a failing hard drive ,but can't be certain without seeing the earlier errors, which likely are not recorded in the logs.

Comment: It's been running for hours now, what should I do please.

Comment: It's not going to progress, may as well shut it off.  Unless you can get the first error that caused this and post it here, not much we can help with.  Next step is diagnostics and data recovery.